# Swift-UICollectionView in UIView Container

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have three sections, the header and a container where a tab bar can facilitate transition of pages all within that container. I want to build a UI like the figure below.[image: Objective]

My approach is to create two container views one for the header and the other for tabbar and selected pages. The tabbar and selected pages are UICollectionViewCell. So I will be putting UICollectionViewCell in a UIView container.

in my BusinessHomeViewController.swift file

```
class BusinessHomeViewController: UIViewController {
 let businessPagesContainer: BusinessPages = {
   let bp = BusinessPages()
    return bp
}()
  func setupbusinessPagesContainerView(){
    businessPagesContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    businessPagesContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    businessPagesContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: businessDescriptionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageToggleContainer.topAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
    menuBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pageToggleContainer.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            view.addSubview(businessPagesContainer)
              setupbusinessPagesContainerView()
    }
    }
```

In my BusinessPages.swift file

```
import UIKit

class BusinessPages: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

When I run the app, it crashes and gave this error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". Is my approach wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running into this problem make sure that you go to Main.storyboard, RIGHT click on the yellow box icon (view controller) at the top of the phone outline and DELETE the outlet(s) with yellow flags.

[image]

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard, I building this programmatically